# How to drop '_merge' column in Pandas.merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am sorting 2 dataframes according to its accuracy. So I merge 2 df with strict conditions with `how='outer', indicator=True` at first then save it to a df called 'perfect'. Later I extract `left_only and right_only` from _merge column to two new dfs. Then I merge these two df with simple conditions  `how='outer', indicator=True` and save new df as 'partial match'. But when I do this I get eeror 
`ValueError: Cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column` 
because I used `indicator = True` again but I need that indicator to apply for unmatched rows (ie, left only and right only) and put them for much simpler conditions.

How can I drop that merge column? Or how can I remove this ValueError?

`_merge` It is not appearing in df.columns, so I am unable to `drop(['_merge') or del df._merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'string' for `indicator` instead of True. [See docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge)

> indicatorbool or str, default False If True, adds a column to output
>   DataFrame called “_merge” with information on the source of each row.
>   If string, column with information on source of each row will be added
>   to output DataFrame, and column will be named value of string.
>   Information column is Categorical-type and takes on a value of
>   “left_only” for observations whose merge key only appears in ‘left’
>   DataFrame, “right_only” for observations whose merge key only appears
>   in ‘right’ DataFrame, and “both” if the observation’s merge key is
>   found in both.

Then the second time you merge, use a different 'string' for indicator.

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'key':np.arange(0,10), 'dataA':np.arange(100,110)})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'key':np.arange(5,15), 'dataB':np.arange(100,110)})
dfA.merge(dfB, on='key', indicator='Ind', how='outer')
```

Output:

```
    key  dataA  dataB         Ind
0     0  100.0    NaN   left_only
1     1  101.0    NaN   left_only
2     2  102.0    NaN   left_only
3     3  103.0    NaN   left_only
4     4  104.0    NaN   left_only
5     5  105.0  100.0        both
6     6  106.0  101.0        both
7     7  107.0  102.0        both
8     8  108.0  103.0        both
9     9  109.0  104.0        both
10   10    NaN  105.0  right_only
11   11    NaN  106.0  right_only
12   12    NaN  107.0  right_only
13   13    NaN  108.0  right_only
14   14    NaN  109.0  right_only
```